# Как работает функция вершинного шейдера OpenGL gl_ClipDistance?

Tags: opengl

Есть какая-либо информация на этот счёт или простой пример? Мне показалась, эта функция довольно интересной, но возникли трудности в её реализации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gl_ClipDistance` - это не функция, а **одна из частей** `input'a` или `output'a` вершинного или геометрического шейдера.

*Если в соответствующем шейдере задать этот параметр, то можно производить клиппинг произвольных вершин на основании расстояния до соответствующих плоскостей.*

**Пример использования** в геометрическом шейдере можно найти [здесь.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718894/using-gl-clipdistance-in-a-geometry-shader)

---

В этом аспекте не очень понятна фраза про трудности с ее реализацией, хотя, я конечно могу допустить, что вы занимаетесь какой-нибудь задачей типа, например, портирования компилятора GLSL на мобильные девайсы.

*В таком случае имеет смысл глянуть, например, на библиотеку [Mesa3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718894/using-gl-clipdistance-in-a-geometry-shader) и посмотреть как соответствующие вещи реализованы там, благо `opensource.`*

Comment: Геометрические шейдеры я пока использовать не собираюсь, но ваш пример я думаю мне пригодится.

Comment: >В этом аспекте не очень понятна фраза про трудности с ее реализацией, хотя, я конечно могу допустить, что вы занимаетесь какой-нибудь задачей типа, например, портирования компилятора GLSL на мобильные девайсы.
 Тогда бы он знал, что это не функция. Просто не корректно задан вопрос.  
>Геометрические шейдеры я пока использовать не собираюсь, но ваш пример я думаю мне пригодится.
 Вряд ли. Без геометрических шейдеров вершины отсекать нельзя.